# Delphi 6 Exe on Vista: Problems with GetWindowText

Tags: delphi, windows-vista

I have an exe file compiled with Delphi 6 under Windows XP that uses a combination of EnumWindows and GetWindowText to find a window (not belonging to the exe itself) with a specific title.

The behaviour is as expected under Windows XP. On Vista computers however, it doesn't seem to work.

As the mentioned Delphi version doesn't run on Vista, I cannot change and test this directly.

However, I will try to create a modified exe on the XP computer that outputs some additional data and copy it to the Vista computer.

I would just like to ask whether anybody has any information whether there are specific problems known with exe files compiled with Delphi 6 running on Vista regarding EnumWindows/GetWindowText.

The exe uses EnumWindows and GetWindowText to find the handle of a certain window in order to then parse the title of that window in a timer event. The window title is the application name plus the name of the file opened in that application (if any file is opened). The Delphi exe analyses/uses this file name, does something with it and behaves in a certain way.

On Vista the expected behaviour does not appear, thus I presume that the window handle is not found cause GetWindowText does somehow not return the text. Another reason of course could be that EnumWindows does not work properly and the window handle of the window that the exe is looking for is never send to the EnumWindowsProc.

Comment: Delphi 7 runs on Vista (with admin priviliges, of course). Are you sure that Delphi 6 doesn't run?

Comment: Delphi 6 runs on Vista and does so without admin privileges

Comment: Delphi 6 runs fine on Vista (even w/o admin privileges) if you install it somewhere other than %PROGRAMFILES%.

Comment: The reason you've given for not investigating this problem is that your version of Delphi doesn't run on your version of Windows. Since that reason is bogus, please install Delphi on Windows and investigate the problem properly, and then update your question here so it reflects what's really happening. If the API function fails, tell us the error code. If it succeeds, tell us what output you were expecting and what you got instead. Don't "presume" that the handle isn't found; use the debugger and *know* what happens.

Comment: Delphi 6 will run under non-privileged user if installed into Program Files, see one of questions regarding installing D7 on Windows 6.0+, recipe is the same.

Comment: Also, a tip: use WM_GETTEXT instead

Comment: Don't remember if it is relevant, but Raymond's book and site contain this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx.

Comment: Actually you should use GetWindowText as Raymond explains

Comment: Thanks very much for those insightful comments, I will most certainly try to install Delphi 6 on my computer. The error message that I received when I tried that before didn't give me the impression that it was "just" a problem with UAC/write rights in the %PROGRAMFILES%.

Comment: It's hard to help solve the problem you might be having when you say "the error message I received" without saying what that error message actually said. Something to remember in the future: We only know what you tell us, and we can't see your screen from here. :) Post the **exact** error message (including any memory addresses in the case of an access violation or other exception); words like "got an error" or "the error message" alone are meaningless.

Comment: @David Heffernan, WM_GETTEXT is perfectly fine as Raymond Chen explains, look at pros and cons. Precautions for hung case assumed.

Comment: -1. "question does not show any research effort."

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that there has been no change in window title from XP to Vista, there's not much that can go wrong here. I'd hazard a guess that the problem is due to UIPI. This is part of the security enhancements of Vista and it means that processes can only send messages to other processes that have equal or lower integrity level. Is this other process running elevated?

Other than that your best bet is to run this under the debugger. Delphi 6 most certainly does run on Vista. It was written before UAC and so doesn't get on well with having no rights to write to its install directory. So, install it to somewhere in your user profile or C:\Delphi6 – basically anywhere that standard users have write access.

Finally, don't fall into the trap of running Delphi elevated. This will confound the UIPI issue if indeed that is an issue here.

Good luck!